# How to proof that D(f) is borel measurable

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

I need to proof that the Borel of $D(f)$ is measurable. The assumption is that a function $f$ is just a random function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$. $D(f)$ are the points where $f$ is discontinuous. $f$ itself is not necessary measurable.

This is all the info the teacher gave me.

I really would like some theory on where to start with this problem,

Thanks in advance!

Erik

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** The set of points where $f$ is continuous is a $G_\delta$ set. The set of points of discontinuity is then the complement of a measurable set and therefore measurable.

If you are stuck on the proof, you can find one [here.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%CE%B4_set#Properties)